# Why the below objects are not equals in Java?

Tags: java, object, equals

IDE: Eclipse; Language: Java core

```
package p1;

public class StringTestA {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object o1 = new StringTestA();
        Object o2 = new StringTestA();

        StringTestA o3 = new StringTestA();
        StringTestA o4 = new StringTestA();

        if (o1.equals(o2)) {
            System.out.println("Object o1 and o2 are eqals");

        }

        if (o3.equals(o4)) {
            System.out.println("Object o3 and o4 are eqals");
        }

    }

    public boolean equals(StringTestA other) {
        System.out.println("StringTestA equals mathod reached");
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
  StringTestA equals method reached
  Object o3 and o4 are equals
```

No output if equals in not overridden.

**Question:** why `System.out.println("Object o1 and o2 are eqals");` line is not printed as equals is returning true;

Answer (score 8):

You are not overriding `equals(Object)`.  The argument must be an `Object`, not `StringTestA`.  You are instead *overloading* `equals` (creating a different method with the same name).

Always annotate methods you wish to override with `@Override`.  Doing so will cause a compile error if you happen to make a mistake in the method declaration, as you did here.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: If you override the equals(), you MUST also override hashCode(). Otherwise a violation of the general contract for Object.hashCode will occur, which can have unexpected repercussions when your class is in conjunction with all hash-based collections.

Comment: @AndreaBorgogelliAvveduti: While this is true and good advice, it is tangential to the question.  For all we know, OP did override hashCode but didn't include it because it had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I wouldn't call it irrelevant. It *is* only tangentially related. I'd certainly have mentioned it as a side comment at the end of the answer, e.g., "Side note: If you're overriding `equals`, you have to override `hashCode` too." (+1, btw, good explanation, particularly re the annotation.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: You're right.  It's a good reminder.  But it belongs as a comment on the question, not an answer.